# php jquery json request each

Tags: php, jquery, json

my jquery is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
setInterval(function() {
$('#divToRefresh').load('get.php');
}, 100);  
});
// ]]></script>
```

the result of get.php is

```
{"dir":"down","sym":"oo","b":"1.35460","a":"1.35465"} {"dir":"down","sym":"pp","b":"1.64263","a":"1.64273"} {"dir":"down","sym":"qq","b":"104.498","a":"104.502"} {"dir":"up","sym":"rr","b":"0.88183","a":"0.88188"} {"dir":"down","sym":"ss","b":"1.09551","a":"1.09558"}
```

i need to display like following

```
ONE : 1.35451 / 1.35454   |     TWO : 171.880 / 171.892   |     GBP / NZD : 1.97260 / 1.97316
```

any help..

Comment: Please add what code is generating output on get.php

Comment: You can format the desired output in `get.php` itself, Since you have used `.load()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading the data directly to 'divToRefresh' you can use a callback function to reformat the data.
I am assuming that the data you are receiving is a PHP array so you will need to parse it to JSON format so you can conveniently access it via Javascript.

```
$('#mydiv').load('get.php',function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        var formatted_output = json.dir + '/' + json.sym;//do whatever formatting you want
        $('#mydiv').html(formatted_output);
    });
```

The result you are sending from the PHP file is not a valid JSON for a multi dimensions array. 
If you are sending it all at once it should be in the following format (or you will have problems parsing it):

```
[{"dir":"down","sym":"oo","b":"1.35460","a":"1.35465"},{"dir":"down","sym":"pp","b":"1.64263","a":"1.64273"},{"dir":"down","sym":"qq","b":"104.498","a":"104.502"},{"dir":"up","sym":"rr","b":"0.88183","a":"0.88188"},{"dir":"down","sym":"ss","b":"1.09551","a":"1.09558"}]
```

Basically every group of elements such as `{element,element,element}` need to be separated with a comma and the entire json should be wrapped with [] i.e `[{element,element},{element,element},{element,element}]`

You can then build a formatted text from the individual elements:

```
var formatted_output = json[0].dir + '/' + json[0].sym + ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this the result you receive ALL AT ONCE? or at different times, 1 row at a time? You can access them by 'json.dir', 'json.sim', etc.;